# "На счет" в данном случае слитно или нет?

Tags: орфография

"На счет офисных столов..."

Answer (score 1):

Производный предлог *насчет* пишется слитно, он синонимичен предлогу *О*. *Поговорить насчет столов - поговорить о столах.* *На счет* пишется раздельно, если это существительное *счет* и предлог *О*. *Положить деньги на счёт.*

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение к ответу Ларf

"Дорогая Екатерина 1. Давайте поговорим **насчёт** вознаграждения Ларf. Например, я не возражаю, чтобы Вы положили 100 рублей **на счёт** Ларf."

Comment: А самому слабо? Да Вы еще и жадина!

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае - слитно.

Обсуждение потихонечку превращается в театр абсурда.
Я не представляю контекста, при котором офисные столы имели бы собственный счет в каком-либо из значений (вернее сказать - воплощений): бухгалтерском, игровом, музыкальном или каком ещё.

Максимально, что можно предположить, будучи по сю сторону забора сумасшедшего дома, - "счет об оплате офисных столов". (Который на самом деле - счет-фактура). **Вот на этот счет** можно при желании поставить поллитру и положить селёдку. Но за более чем длительное общение с бухгалтерами никогда не слышал, чтобы **счет на оплату товара** называли бы **счетом товара**. Так что даже в этом значении было бы "счет на/за офисные столы", а не "счет офисных столов".

Answer (score 0):

Нужен контекст. Но подозреваю, что речь все-таки идет на о счетах офисных столов. Поэтому пишется слитно - "насчет".